# producer.headerMode default value

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

probably anyone know which value is default for `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<bindingName>.producer.header-mode` in spring-cloud-stream-kafka-binder?

The problem is because in spring-cloud stream documentation we have

> Default: Depends on the binder implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default is `headers` for the Apache Kafka binder.

In general, you can assume that for middleware that supports headers natively (e.g. Kafka since 0.11.0.0), the default will be `headers`; for middleware that has no support for headers, it will be `embeddedHeaders` or `none` depending on what the developer chose.